# How do I rebuild data-raw using roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a package that uses a pre-built dataset that may be modified over time by other parts of the package.  Specifically, I have files that I add to the `inst` directory that will be indexed to make a data.frame.  The indexing does not take a very long time (about 15-30 seconds), but it is longer than something I'd like to do on every package load.

Is there a way to automate the indexing so that it will occur with `roxygen2::roxygenize()`?  What I'd really love to have happen is that an R function from the package would run any time I run `devtools::document()`.  I think that this is possible by creating a custom roclet, but I don't understand quite how I would do this in practice.

Comment: I don't know how to have `roxygen2` do that, it seems a bit out of its intended purpose. Can you cook the data into `./data/*.rda` instead? Whether that data is combined by scripts in `./inst/` or `./data-raw/` or somewhere else is mostly your (author/maintainer) preference and what access you want package-users to have to the process.

Comment: I definitely can and have used data-raw to put data into a package before.  The difference here is that there will likely be many contributors to this package with parts that need to be put into this raw data.  I want to have an automated update to the data which would be done without contributor intervention.  My thought was putting it in the documentation step, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I understand. Might I suggest a set of package functions (exported or not) that standardize the data munging and saving it to the appropriate location. Having said that, one night try to abuse the `#' @examples` portion that is run (e.g., during `devtools::document()`), where the "example" code has file-saving side effects. (Untested.) I know if no formal way otherwise.

Comment: `s/night/might/` :-/

Answer (score 0):

After reading more documentation, I found the answer to the question.  The `@examples` idea from @r2evans helped me find something that is more directly targeting something like this.  I used `#' @eval my_function()` where `my_function()` is an exported function in the package that builds the data and generates the documentation for the data.